# 2 breadcrumbs for 2 menus in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm using 2 different menus in 2 different blocks. They are enabled / disabled depending on the the pages users arevisiting.

Now, I have an issue with the breadcrumbs: they only work with the main menu and not the second one.

I need to automatically have the breadcrumbs the other menu as well.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal's menu system sets only one active menu at a time: if you're trying to have two breadcrumbs at the same time on the same page, you're going to need to use [`menu_set_active_menu_name()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/menu_set_active_menu_name/6) to do some juggling back and forth.

However, if you're just trying to have one show up, consider using the [Menu Breadcrumb](http://drupal.org/project/menu_breadcrumb) module, which automatically sets the active menu based on the page. You also have the ability to set menu priority for pages that exist in more than one menu.

Comment: I'm actually using "menu breadcrumbs", and I've checked both menus in the settings. But I can only give priority to one of the two menus. Some pages belong to both menus (I have 2 languages and each menu displays according to the selected language). In conclusion, if the pages are translated in two languages and belong to both menus, the first menu is always picked up for breadcrumbs, even if I'm using the second one.

Comment: That's Drupal core's behavior: only one active menu at a time. If you're just trying to localize the the same content, setting up two different menus isn't the way to go: use core's Content Translation and Locale modules to provide language-specific versions of the same content and IA.

Comment: The point is that my english menu has completely different structure of the italian one. But many pages have both english and italian version.

Comment: Is this a valid point ? I mean, do you know how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

This question is not strictly programming related, however:

Drupal breadcrumbs follow the menu-items as they are enabled. Regardless of whether the menu-items are visible, and regardless of what menu(containers) hold the menu. Items that are not in the menu (such as nodes!) will not have a breadcrumb.

That said, there is an exception, modules can override the breadcrumb with `drupal_set_breadcrumb()`, if they do so, the last one to set the breadcrumb gets to set the breadcrumb. E.g. taxonomy module sets the breadcrumb on taxonomy-pages.

1. You could set the breadcrumbs hardcoded in a module.
2. You should investigate why breadcrumbs don't follow your menu's in this case.
3. You could investigate modules that allow tweaking the breadcrumb behaviour, such as [hansel](http://drupal.org/project/hansel)